# Dynamically hide mutiselect for different actions

Tags: multistore, controllers, ui, multiselect

In Magento 2, I have 2 actions in my controller: `newAction() and edit()`.

Both actions will use for a same form with few inputs. Among them is multiselect for store selection. I want to show it when I creating the brand, and hide it while editing the brand. Form realised as ui-component and coded in XML.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much!